# on importing code Error:(18, 87) No resource found that matches the given name in drawable

Tags: android, json, xml, sqlite, build

I am trying to find code for showing json parsed data in list and storing that in sqlite  and i got tutorial of http://www.appifiedtech.net/2015/06/19/android-json-parsing-with-sqlite-example/ but the problem is when i had opened project then i got error messages say : -

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72211Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42211Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources
AAPT out(847410793) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(1366595768) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(1828156968) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(1327027863) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(1159461287) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(739729571) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(2126272648) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(1697114705) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(1327027863) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(1828156968) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(69078674) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(1828156968) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(1697114705) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(2126272648) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(1893575341) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(739729571) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(1327027863) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(457494946) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(457494946) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(847410793) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(1223780838) : No Delegate set : lost message:Crunching D:\collageprojectverygood\showjsoninlistandsaveinsqlite\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.1.1\res\drawable-xxxhdpi-v4\abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha.png
AAPT out(1223780838) : No Delegate set : lost message:Crunching single PNG file: D:\collageprojectverygood\showjsoninlistandsaveinsqlite\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.1.1\res\drawable-xxxhdpi-v4\abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha.png
AAPT out(1223780838) : No Delegate set : lost message:  Output file: D:\collageprojectverygood\showjsoninlistandsaveinsqlite\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxxhdpi-v4\abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha.png
AAPT out(1223780838) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(1223780838) : No Delegate set : lost message:Crunching D:\collageprojectverygood\showjsoninlistandsaveinsqlite\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.1.1\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012.9.png
AAPT out(1223780838) : No Delegate set : lost message:Crunching single PNG file: D:\collageprojectverygood\showjsoninlistandsaveinsqlite\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.1.1\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012.9.png
AAPT out(1223780838) : No Delegate set : lost message:  Output file: D:\collageprojectverygood\showjsoninlistandsaveinsqlite\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012.9.png
AAPT out(1223780838) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT err(1828156968): D:\collageprojectverygood\showjsoninlistandsaveinsqlite\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.1.1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(1828156968): D:\collageprojectverygood\showjsoninlistandsaveinsqlite\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.1.1\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(1828156968): D:\collageprojectverygood\showjsoninlistandsaveinsqlite\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.1.1\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(1223780838): D:\collageprojectverygood\showjsoninlistandsaveinsqlite\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.1.1\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(1223780838): D:\collageprojectverygood\showjsoninlistandsaveinsqlite\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.1.1\res\drawable-ldrtl-xxxhdpi-v17\abc_ic_menu_copy_mtrl_am_alpha.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(847410793): D:\collageprojectverygood\showjsoninlistandsaveinsqlite\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.1.1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(847410793): D:\collageprojectverygood\showjsoninlistandsaveinsqlite\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.1.1\res\drawable-xxxhdpi-v4\abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_mtrl_alpha.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(1327027863): D:\collageprojectverygood\showjsoninlistandsaveinsqlite\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.1.1\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(1327027863): D:\collageprojectverygood\showjsoninlistandsaveinsqlite\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.1.1\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(1327027863): D:\collageprojectverygood\showjsoninlistandsaveinsqlite\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.1.1\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(1893575341): D:\collageprojectverygood\showjsoninlistandsaveinsqlite\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.1.1\res\drawable-ldrtl-xhdpi-v17\abc_ic_menu_copy_mtrl_am_alpha.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(1366595768): D:\collageprojectverygood\showjsoninlistandsaveinsqlite\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.1.1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(457494946): D:\collageprojectverygood\showjsoninlistandsaveinsqlite\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.1.1\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(457494946): D:\collageprojectverygood\showjsoninlistandsaveinsqlite\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.1.1\res\drawable-ldrtl-xxxhdpi-v17\abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(739729571): D:\collageprojectverygood\showjsoninlistandsaveinsqlite\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.1.1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(739729571): D:\collageprojectverygood\showjsoninlistandsaveinsqlite\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.1.1\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(1159461287): D:\collageprojectverygood\showjsoninlistandsaveinsqlite\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.1.1\res\drawable-ldrtl-xxhdpi-v17\abc_ic_menu_copy_mtrl_am_alpha.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(2126272648): D:\collageprojectverygood\showjsoninlistandsaveinsqlite\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.1.1\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(69078674): D:\collageprojectverygood\showjsoninlistandsaveinsqlite\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.1.1\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(1697114705): D:\collageprojectverygood\showjsoninlistandsaveinsqlite\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.1.1\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(2126272648): D:\collageprojectverygood\showjsoninlistandsaveinsqlite\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.1.1\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(1697114705): D:\collageprojectverygood\showjsoninlistandsaveinsqlite\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.1.1\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
D:\collageprojectverygood\showjsoninlistandsaveinsqlite\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.1.1\res\drawable\abc_item_background_holo_dark.xml
Error:(20, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark').
Error:(21, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark').
D:\collageprojectverygood\showjsoninlistandsaveinsqlite\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.1.1\res\drawable\abc_item_background_holo_light.xml
Error:(20, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light').
Error:(21, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light').
D:\collageprojectverygood\showjsoninlistandsaveinsqlite\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.1.1\res\drawable\abc_list_selector_holo_dark.xml
Error:(22, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark').
Error:(23, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark').
D:\collageprojectverygood\showjsoninlistandsaveinsqlite\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.1.1\res\drawable\abc_list_selector_holo_light.xml
Error:(22, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light').
Error:(23, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light').
D:\collageprojectverygood\showjsoninlistandsaveinsqlite\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\AndroidJsonParsingSQlite-master\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.1.1\res\drawable\abc_textfield_search_material.xml
Error:(18, 87) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha').
Error:(19, 89) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha').
Error:(20, 58) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha').
Error:(21, 29) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha').
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\sai\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 21.632 secs
Information:13 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

I tried a lot but solution is not getting or solving my problem .
Here is my build.gradle code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.appified.jsonparsingexample"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

and code for  build tool

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These is because of not importing project properly .Now i got right answer